# How do I use markdown-it.js to parse content in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown

I'm trying to figure out how to parse markdown content that is already in a div:

```
<div id="markdown-content">
 ## Heading
</div>
```

I've been looking at jquery markdown parsers on github such Markdown-it, but can't find any with docs that show how to parse existing content. Markdown-it.js seems to be popular, but their only browser usage example is:

```
var md = window.markdownit();
var result = md.render('# markdown-it rulezz!');
```

I'm not sure how to apply that to parsing content that's already in a div, is it possible to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is get the markdown text and parse it. Then put it somewhere. You could even put it back where you got it from.

```
var markdown = $('#markdown-content').html();
var html = md.render(markdown);
$('#output').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will parse an input string and return a list of block tokens.

```
var md     = window.markdownit();
var result = md.parse( document.querySelector('#markdown-content').textContent, {} );
```

See https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/#MarkdownIt.parse